# How can I copy values from some spreadsheets that are in one subfolder to another spreadsheet with app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy values ​​from several spreadsheets that are in subfolders, for that I investigated how to search files between folders and subfolders with a script like the following ...

```
function listFolders(folder) {

folder = folder || DriveApp.getRootFolder();

var name = folder.getName();

var files = folder.getFiles();

while ( files.hasNext() ) {
  Logger.log(name + " :: " + files.next().getName());
}

var subfolders = folder.getFolders();

while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
  listFolders(subfolders.next());
}
```

Until here it makes the search of between folders and subfolders of all the 
files and then I try to realize a condition which if it finds the folder "measurement", then copy from the files that there are some data to another spreadsheet, but it does not realize the condition and I do not know why...

```
   if( folder == "Measurement"){
   while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   var bring = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId());

   var srceSheet = bring.getSheets()[0];

    var lastRow = srceSheet.getLastRow();
    var range = srceSheet.getRange("A"+(lastRow)+":D"+(lastRow));
    var values = range.getValues();


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var SSsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
    var getRow = SSsheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var ssRange = SSsheet.getRange(getRow, 2, values.length,
    values[0].length);
    ssRange.setValues(values);


  }
 }
}
```

I do not know what I can have wrong, if the condition is badly declared or another way I investigate is to put the name of the files with this condition `'fullText contains "hello world"'` or this other `'name contains "hello" and name contains "goodbye"'` Declaring beforehand a variable that contains this as... `var file = DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFiles('name contains "hello" and name contains "goodbye"')`.

Comment: If the origin folder will always be "Measurement" then it's better to grab its ID and use `DriveApp.getFolderById(id)` rather than iterating over all folders. The other thing is that you variale `folder` is of the type `Folder`, so you can't compare it to the string "Measurement". You can change to `if( folder.getName() == "Measurement")`

Comment: Yes, always the source folder will be called `Measurement`, 
the problem is that it is not just a folder but many are called `Measurement` so I can not declare the method with the ID, thanks, you made me realize something that I let go, but for now it's still not working, I'll keep trying and I hope someone can guide me to solve this :D

Comment: This line of code: `if( folder == "Measurement"){`  If `folder` is not a string, then it will never be equal.  You should have a variable named `folderName` and use that in your code.  If `folder` is a folder object, then it will never equal the string "Measurement"  I'm going to assume that a variable named `folder` is a folder object, and not the folder name.  It seems like you need to thoroughly debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for helping me, I was able to solve my question, investigate a little more and I found this method `file.list` of this page [Developers.Google](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters) and my script was like this ...

```
function SearchFiles() {
var searchFor ='fullText contains "Test"';
var names =[];
var fileIds=[];
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(searchFor);
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileId = file.getId();
  fileIds.push(fileId);
  var name = file.getName();
  names.push(name);

  var bring = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()); 
  var dePr = bring.getSheetByName("Sheet1 ");
  var veEq = bring.getSheetByName("Sheet2 ");


    var ltRowDe = dePr.getLastRow();
    var rgDe    = dePr.getRange("B"+(ltRowDe)+":E"+(ltRowDe));
    var valDe   = rgDe.getValues();


    var ltRowVe  = veEq.getLastRow();
    var rgVe    = veEq.getRange("O"+(ltRowVe)+":P"+(ltRowVe));
    var valVe    = rgVe.getValues();


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var ssDe = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet  1");
    var getRowDe = ssDe.getLastRow() + 1;
    var ssRgDe = ssDe.getRange(getRowDe, 5, valDe.length, valDe[0].length).setValues(valDe);  


    var ssVe = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2");
    var getRowVe = ssVe.getLastRow() + 1;
    var ssRgVe = ssVe.getRange(getRowVe, 7, valVe.length, valVe[0].length).setValues(valVe); 

}  
}
```

Basically what my script does is that it performs a search by the drive of all the files that are called `Test` and it brings me the last data of the sheets that you specify of all those files to another spreadsheet. Thanks for the help and I hope that some day someone will serve this script. =D